# How can I close an out-of-browser Silverlight window?

Tags: silverlight, out-of-browser

I want to be able to close a Silverlight window when running out of browser. I know it is possible to do this in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks. Interestingly, I asked my question before this method was added, so it wasn't possible to do this when I asked the question.

Comment: FYI This method is limited to trusted applications or when called from a user-initiated event. See the [Remarks section of the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.close(v=vs.95)) for details.